# Can't hide keyboard in UIViewController stack when UIAlertView is on screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uikit, uialertview

I just spent most of a day tracking down a very strange case where calling resignFirstResponder on the active UITextField did not hide the keyboard, even though the textfield was the first responder. This happens when I push a view controller on top of another view controller with an active text field. The keyboard goes away (as expected). But if I bring the keyboard back by touching a textfield in the 2nd view controller, subsequent calls to resignFirstResponder have no effect.

Here's simple code to reproduce the issue. This code is a view controller with a nav bar button to hide the keyboard, and another to push another copy of itself (with a confirmation UIAlertView). The first copy works without problem. However, if you push a 2nd copy (when the first copy has a visible keyboard) it is impossible to dismiss the keyboard. This only happens if there is a UIAlertView (the confirmation) on the screen when the 2nd copy is pushed. If you remove the `#define ALERT` line, everything works.

Does anyone know what is happening here? It looks like the UIALertView window is somehow interfering with the keyboard and keeping it's window from disappearing, which then confuses the next view. Is there any solution here other than pushing the 2nd view controller on a timer after the UIALertView is gone?

Sorry for the complex description. This is runnable code. I hope that the code is clear.

```
@implementation DemoViewController

- (id) init {
    if (!(self = [super init])) 
        return nil;

    return self; 
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [_inputTextfield release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) loadView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    _inputTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0., 0., 320., 44.)];
    _inputTextfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    _inputTextfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    _inputTextfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    _inputTextfield.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    _inputTextfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    _inputTextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    [view addSubview:_inputTextfield];

    self.view = view;
    [view release];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIButton *downButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [downButton setTitle: @"keyboard down" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [downButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [downButton sizeToFit];    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:downButton] autorelease];

    UIButton *nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [nextButton setTitle: @"next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [nextButton sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:nextButton] autorelease];;

}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [_inputTextfield resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void) downButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [_inputTextfield resignFirstResponder];
}

#define ALERT

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.cancelButtonIndex == buttonIndex) {
        return; 
    }
    [self _nextButtonPressed];
}

- (void) _nextButtonPressed {
    DemoViewController *nextViewController = [[DemoViewController alloc] init];    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController];
    [nextViewController release];
}

- (void) nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {
#ifdef ALERT   
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    alert.message = @"Next view?";  
    alert.cancelButtonIndex = [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
#else   
    [self _nextButtonPressed];    
#endif
}
```

Comment: Have you tried resigning the first responder on the first view controller before presenting the second view controller?

Comment: Yes, in viewWillDisappear. Sorry, that did not make it into my demo code. But it has no effect.

Comment: Ok, Have you tried using [self.view endEditing:YES]? this should end editing on all subviews as well.

Comment: No. But I believe that that just calls resignFirstResponder. resignFirstResponder is being called. textField.isFirstResponder == YES before the call to resignFirstResponder and NO afterward.

Comment: I'd suggest you either try: 1. to debug it, try to see who remains the first responder after you resign the last one, just to see which is causing you trouble 2. just to truncate and see where it comes from, try using endEditing.

Comment: I've looked at who remains first responder. [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)] == nil after I resign the textField, but the keyboard remains.

Comment: Maybe a bug? although it's unlikely. I've added a 3rd approach if you ever get tired of figuring that one out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4589/discussion-between-wombat57-and-alon-amir)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had bad luck resigning your first responders, here are a few solutions that might help:

1. Determine who has remained the first responder after your last call to resign first responder.
2. Try resigning all first responders by a single call to self.view (container view)

   ```
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
   ```
3. **ONLY** if you've tried all the above methods and none worked, consider using this workaround.

   ```
   -(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
     NSArray *wins = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
     if ([wins count] > 1) {
       UIWindow *keyboardWindow = [wins objectAtIndex:1];
       keyboardWindow.hidden = YES;
     }
     return YES;
   }
   ```